# how to check the format of a filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, filesystems

I would like to check, in a bash script, on what filesystem type a directory is.

The idea is something like

```
if [path] is on a [filesystem] filesystem then
   filesystem specific command
end if
```

Comment: Do you want the mount point or the filesystem type? What would your desired output be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `df`. You can pass it a path, and it will give you the filesystem information for that path. If you need the filesystem type, use the `-T` switch, like so:

```
$ df -T test
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4 182634676 32337180 141020160  19% /home
```

To extract the filesystem type, you can parse it (use the `-P` switch to avoid `df` breaking lines if the device part is too long):

```
$ df -PT test | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'
ext4
```

So you can use that value in an `if` construct like so:

```
if [ "$(df -PT "$path" | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}')" = "ext4" ] ; then
  it is an ext4 filesystem
fi
```

Beware that the device column can contain spaces (but it's rare), in which case the parsing will fail.

Answer (score 13):

On a system with the GNU stat command installed (as with pretty well any standard Linux distro), you can get the fs type for a given file without requiring any parsing using the `stat` command:

```
stat -f -c %T filename
```

`-f` tells `stat` to provide information about the file-system instead of the file, and `-c %T` sets the output format to include only the human-readable filesystem type (`%T`).

So you could use that (in bash) as:

```
if [[ $(stat -f -c %T filename) == ext4 ]]; then
  # ext4 specific command
fi
```

`man stat` will provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

With `findmnt` (part of `util-linux`):

```
findmnt -no fstype -T /path/to/file
```

When using the option

```
-T, --target path
```

if the path is not a mountpoint file or directory, `findmnt` checks  path  elements in reverse order to get the mountpoint. The other two options suppress the header line: `-n, --noheading` and select the column(s) to be listed: `-o, --output`

---

`df` from `coreutils` has a similar option `--output=` to print only certain fields, like `fstype` e.g.:

```
df --output=fstype /path/to/file
```

there's no option to remove the header though, so you'll have to pipe the output to e.g. `| sed 1d`

Comment: A cute `findmnt` tool, even with line-drawing TUI output. Thanks!