# How to get filesystem info for a specific file?

Tags: mount, posix

What is the best way to find out file system information about a file.

For example, if I have a file

```
/media/xyz/path/to/file.ext
```

And `/etc/fstab` contains

```
//server1/Share1 /media/xyz cifs option1=value1,...
```

How can I determine that the file is on a Samba share, that it has the local path `/path/to/file.ext` and with what options the file system was mounted?

Is parsing the output of `mount` a portable solution? Or parse `findmnt`? Is there a POSIX-compliant way to achieve that?

Comment: `df /path/to/file` should show the partition or mount.

Comment: Thanks @thrig, that makes the first step. What would be the best way to get info like mount options from there?

Comment: On Linux, I can parse `/proc/mounts`. Is there a BSD/OSX compatible way to achieve the same?

Comment: just by looking at files? you can't! that is the beauty if unix-like operating systems, applications can access them by using path irrespective of their physical location

Comment: @edwardtorvalds No, not just by looking at files, that's why I asked about parsing `mount` etc. for getting filesystem and options etc. I'm still not sure about the best way to find this information in *BSD and OSX. I haven't had time to work on the library that requires this but will feedback once I do. From what I saw, `mount -P` seems pretty reliable across Linux/BSD.

Answer (score 1):

stat(1) is a portable way to find out some of these information, e.g.:

```
stat --file-system --format="%T" /media/xyz/path/to/file.ext
```

Everything else is very OS-specific, on recent Linux systems you can easily use `findmnt --output` in a script.

Comment: `stat` is also os-specific.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your need correctly, and combining bits from previous answers, the following might be what you need. 
define in script (for example, in your .bashrc)-

```
findpart ()
{
df -h $1|sed 1d|cut -d" " -f1|xargs findmnt -n
}
```

and then you can run it as needed

```
findpart /foo/file.ext
```

Comment: `findmnt` doesn't need all that stuff, it can do this [all by itself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229496)

Comment: theoretically, yes. in practice, i could not get -T to work on centos 6, whereas this solution does.